# Double logging output in Python when trying to display line number - what's wrong here?

Tags: python, logging

I set up logging in a simple script like this. Now I receive all output twice, once in the desired format, once in the standard format. What am I missing? I'm not very good at Python, so please bear with me...

**Setup:**

```py
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
FORMAT = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s()] %(message)s"
formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info('Start Scraping')
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-13 21:00:30,234 INFO     [script.py:33 - <module>()] Start Scraping
2021-05-13 21:00:30,234 __main__     INFO     Start Scraping
```

Comment: I ran your example and it gave me just one line of output. `INFO     [script.py:33 - <module>()] Start Scraping` to be particular.

Comment: do you import this code to other code which may already use logging? Do you run it directly `python script.py` or in some IDE?

Comment: I import another file where I also set up logging. What would be the correct structure to set this up in a scenario where I run scriptA and import scriptB and want logging in both?

Comment: Set `logger.propagate = False` if you don't want the logs from this to go up the logger hierarchy. And probably read/learn about the logger hierarchy too ^_^ https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Thanks, @blues. I will have a look.